# Wrong screen resolution with GPU card connected with displayport->HDMI Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes))

Tags: drivers, nvidia, hdmi, display-resolution

My screen resolution is 1920x1080 when I can get 2520x1080 (lg25UM58).
My card is connected to this screen with a displayport (GPU) to HDMI (Screen)
Is this a problem with the connector ? Have you any ideas ?

Here are my configuration:

```
sudo lshw -C display
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       produit: GM107GL [Quadro K620]
       fabriquant: NVIDIA Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       ressources: irq:133 mémoire:de000000-deffffff mémoire:c0000000-cfffffff mémoire:d0000000-d1ffffff portE/S:e000(taille=128) mémoire:c0000-dffff
```

Kernel info

```
uname -a
Linux thomas-PC 4.15.0-55-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 2 18:22:20 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Xrandr output

```
xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 673mm x 284mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    59.93    50.00    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   2048x1152     59.91  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00    59.95    59.82  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1440x810      59.97  
   1400x1050     74.76    70.00    59.98  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.96    59.80  
   1280x1024     85.02    75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      85.00    60.00  
   1280x800      59.91    59.81    59.97  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    59.86    59.74    50.00    60.00    59.99  
   1152x864     100.00    85.06    85.00    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.00  
   1024x768      85.00    86.96    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1024x576      59.90    59.82    59.96    59.95  
   960x600       60.00    59.93  
   960x540       59.82    59.63    59.99    59.96  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   840x525       85.02    74.96    69.88    60.01    59.88  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       85.14    75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   720x450       59.89  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   720x400       85.04  
   700x525       74.76    59.98  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.96    59.80  
   640x480       85.01    75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93  
   640x400       85.08    59.98    59.88  
   640x360       59.84    59.32    59.86    59.83  
   640x350       85.08  
   512x384       70.07    87.06    60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.82    59.63  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   400x300       72.19  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x240       72.81    60.05  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
   320x175       85.27
```

Nvidia driver is 430 obtained with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430 nvidia-settings
```

What can i do to force the resolution ?
I try

```
cvt 2560 1080 60
```

Output

```
# 2560x1080 59.98 Hz (CVT) hsync: 67.17 kHz; pclk: 230.00 MHz
Modeline "2560x1080_60.00"  230.00  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Adding a mode

```
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_60.00"  230.00  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode DP-0 2560x1080_60.00
```

Wich give me this error :

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  35
  Current serial number in output stream:  36
```